# vscode on linux can't attach to process

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code

When I try to attach to a process to debug using vscode for linux, I hit the following error. Before hitting it, vscode asked me to use superuser which I set it to yes.

```
Error checking for authorization org.freedesktop.policykit.exec: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying
[1] + Done(127)                  /usr/bin/pkexec "/usr/bin/gdb" --interpreter=mi --tty=${DbgTerm} 0<"/tmp/Microsoft-MIEngine-In-va11infa.izd" 1>"/tmp/Microsoft-MIEngine-Out-tczpxhu2.pu5"
```

Comment: possibly related: https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=302811, https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/679255, https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/97v46w/i_think_i_have_an_issue_with_policy_kit/